# How to distribute N regularly spaced bools in an array of M bools?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am having the following problem that I cannot solve.
Let's say I have an array of 100 bools, all false. 
I have a number N < 100 and I want to toggle N of these booleans to true, but so that they appear as regularly spaced as possible. 
This is obviously simple when N divides 100, but how to do it for instance if N = 53?
I naively tried :

```
for(int i =0; i<53; ++i)
    std::cout << i*100/53 <<'\n';
```

to get 53 equaly distributed integers, and in this case I actualy have distincts integers, but I'm not sure this always works. Any pointers on this?

Comment: What do you mean by "equally" distributed? Do you want a random uniform distribution? If so, you can just use the Fisher-Yates shuffle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: I think your code will give "Equally distributed" if by that you mean as regularly spaced as possible. You should note that a random allocation will most likely not actually "appear" very "equally distributed" in that sense.

Comment: The distribution is 'even' (although you will always select item 0, which probably isn't what you expect if N=1... perhaps instead of needing N indices, you need N+1 equally-sized gaps?). But is the important bit to you whether these numbers are all distinct?

Comment: @ChrisNash: yeah the important part is that I toggle exactly N bools, and that they "appear" as regularly spaced as possible

Comment: @jzila : i edited, I just want regularly spaced distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the method you suggest, you will always get distinct integers for i * 100/X and (i + 1) * 100/X as long as X < 100 (as the difference is 100/X, which is > 1). So it's a simple proof by induction that all the integers you obtain this way are unique.

So this is a fine approach. The real question, which only you can answer, is how do you define equally distributed integers?

Perhaps for X > 2, you should always have i[0] and i[99] set to true and divide the space in between equally. For the special case of X = 1, set the middle element (50th or 51st) to true.

Comment: Ok  this is pretty much the explanation I needed, I don't know why I didn't notice that I also increment by > 1 so I always get different indexes.
For the case where X =1, what I can do is equally distribute  99 bools set to false with the same method, and the remaining bool (corresponding to X = 1) will end up in the middle, which is what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is C#, but maybe something like this?

```
    static void Main( string[] args ) {

        bool[] bools = new bool[100];

        decimal incrementor = 100m / 53;
        decimal tracking = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
            tracking += incrementor;
            bools[(int) Math.Round(tracking)] = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the largest number, `P`, less-than-or-equal-to `N`, for which P is a divisor of `M`.

At increments of `P` (beginning at index 0), place a number in the array.

The numbers in the array will be **exactly** as uniformly distributed as possible.

Comment: If I am following correctly, I don't think that would result in the desired number of entries being set to true.  For the values in the OP, (53 and 100), P=50, which means a value is set every 2 entries ... but that only sets 50 to true instead of the desired 53.

Comment: Indeed. There are two constraints here: the regularity of the spacing (approx M/N) and the total number of bools set N, which cannot be satisfied when M%N != 0. The question is quite clear that the second constraint _must_ be met, and the first constraint is merely an optimization criterium